# Jquery .click() not triggering event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a conditional statement to a .click function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function runEffect() {
        var selectedEffect = "blind";
        var form = $("#forms").val();
        if (form == "Equipment") {
            $("#effect2").toggle(selectedEffect, 500);
        } else {
            $("#effect").toggle(selectedEffect, 500);
        }
    };
    $("#button").click(function () {
        runEffect();
    });
});
```

HTML Portion:

```
<select  name="inquiryOptions" id = "forms">
        <option value="" selected></option> 
        <option value="Equipment">Equipment Requested to Site</option>
        <option value="Equipment Return Request">Equipment Return Request</option>
        <option value="Equipment Forwarding Site to Site Request">Equipment Forwarding Site to Site Request</option>
        <option value="Other Move Request">Other Move Request</option>
</select>
<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Next</button>

<div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display:none">
<form action="#" method ="POST" id ="mainForm_3">

...
 </form>
</div>
```

Effect two is exactly the same but with different fields inside the form...
Any feedback is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle?

Comment: I don't see a #effect or #effect2 element..

Comment: 1) there are no elements `#effect` and `#effect2`. 2) you use toggle not quite right. Can you explain what should happen to `#effect` and `#effect2`?

Comment: So what's the problem? I don't see anything wrong with the logic or syntax of your jQuery. BTW, you could use `$("#button").click(runEffect);` instead of `$("#button").click(function () {
        runEffect();
    });`.

Comment: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syspeL9p/, the click event is being triggered, there is another problem. You should use the browser console to debug your js

Comment: Provide sample which replicates your issue. Are you including jQuery UI? Any error in console? Etc?...

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would break your function out of the document ready and then use .on to bind your event handler to your selector:

Take a look at the toggle() in jquery api, as your not using it in the correct manner: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You are also saying to toggle #effect & #effect2 that do not exist on your page. See my fiddle below and you will see what toggling does.

```
function runEffect() {   
    var selectedEffect = "blind";
    var form = $("#forms").val();

    if (form == "Equipment") {
        console.log('Equipment=true');
        $("#effect2").toggle();
    } else {
        console.log('Equipment=false');
        $("#effect").toggle();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").on('click', function () {
        runEffect();
    });
});
```

Now you just need define your selectedEffect.

Here is a fiddle to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/ju9qz4vd/3/

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. I can see your new hear. Don't forget to mark your answers. :)